# PHP Regex capture repeated children as groups inside parent pattern

Tags: php, regex

I want to capture a repeated values wrapped by parentheses within parents.

```
(parent (foo 25) (bar 500) (child (100 10) (300 20) (400 30)))
(parent (foo 80) (bar 130) (child (200 15)))
```

knowing every child can contain one or multiple children `(child (..) ..)` or `(child (..) (..) (..) ..)`

formatted:

```
(parent
    (foo 25)
    (bar 500)
    (child
        // want to capture the below children dynamically (the integers only)
        (100 10)
        (300 20)
        (400 30)
    )
)

// without conflicting with other values in same file
(extra (foo 18) (bar 77))
(different (foo 46) (bar 190))
```

The output i'm trying to get:

```
Array(
    '100 10',
    '300 20',
    '400 30'
)
```

not sure to include things i've tried, they're all wasn't for what i need.

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the elements `(100 10)` would only occur as children, then a regex find all approach might be viable here:

```php
$input = "(parent (foo 25) (bar 500) (child (100 10) (300 20) (400 30)))";
$input = preg_replace("/\(parent (?:\((?!\bchild\b)\w+.*?\) )*/", "", $input);
preg_match_all("/\((\d+ \d+)\)/", $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100 10
    [1] => 300 20
    [2] => 400 30
)
```

Comment: works, can we limit the selective between parentheses only inside the ```(parent ...``` to avoid wrong selections? i can see it's capturing (digits digits), i may have same but inside other than ```(parent ..)``` thanks

Comment: No...for that general case you would be better off writing a parser.  Regex is not very suitable for nested content.

Comment: @AmrSubZero I amended my answer to strip off the parent elements first before doing the regex find all.  This might be enough for you.